# How to automatically export multiple data dumps from a large table in MS ACCESS?

Tags: ms-access, macros, export

I am new to MS ACCESS. I want to export multiple data dumps from a large table containing 1800000+ rows with 10-15 columns... It looks something like this,

```
 MDN, VALUE1, VALUE1, VALUE1, VALUE4 ,...
1234,   X1  ,   Y1  ,   Z1  ,   A1   ,...
2345,   X2  ,   Y2  ,   Z2  ,   A2   ,...
4567,   X2  ,   Y3  ,   Z3  ,   A3   ,...
....
```

What I want to do is, export only the MDN field having X2 value in VALUE1 column. After that I would like to export another set having A3 value in VALUE4 column, and so on. Then I want to put it all in a macro and run it everyday to get the dumps. Also this large table changes everyday, I.e. the values get updated everyday.

I know how to export into text file though.

Please help on how do I build the macro. Googled it a lot but to no avail. :( 
Please help !!

Comment: It looks like this is the question number 13,000,000.

Comment: how many different outputs are required?  If it's a limited number and they don't change much, you could write a query for each output and then a macro that includes an export step for each query.

Comment: No George.. the values do change everyday... I need to spit out 90-100 outputs everyday.... One thing that is fixed is the column... This column is prepared by concatenating 3 VALUE columns.... Hence the issue... The value columns are changed and so is the combination column....I need a macro to automate the whole thing... Macro should be able to export MDNs based on these dynamic combinations....

Comment: You didn't include the column preparation and what it implies. You sate that the combination column changes, and you need to export MDNs based on these, and you didn't include the combination process and result.

Comment: It's just a concatenation of 3 value columns... The combination column will have values like X1Y1Z1 .. Need to export the MDNs based on these combinations